# Which current types can be measured with a Shunt?

Tags: current, current-measurement, high-current, shunt

Which of the following current types are typically measured with the help of a shunt resistor?

- DC
- AC
- Impulses (4/10 us, 8/20 us, longer impulses > 500us?)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @JohnD it is a missing information in my script, which I am not able to find in the net

Comment: all of the above

Comment: All of the above, with impulses dependent on resolution of measuring device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Typically" is tough to pin down.  All 3 can be measured with a shunt, I'd say DC and impulses are more common than AC, which can be measured by a current transformer or Rogowski coil.

A current sense resistor is often used in series with the source of a FET in peak current mode SMPS control, one type of very common impulse application.

Open and closed-loop Hall effect transducers are fairly common too, so what's "typical" kind of varies with the application.